# Transitionend fire function twice in Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, dom-events

I'm learning react js and just creating my first todo app in it. All work fine but when I try to apply some animation or transition my to-do list does not render properly. When I debugged it I found that my transition function fire function twice.

I have tried something like this:

**TodoWrapper.js**

```
  let [todos, setTodos] = useState([]);
  let [todosType, setTodoType] = useState('all');

  const deleteTodo = (todo) => {
    console.log(todo);
    setTodos(todos.filter((item) => (item.id !== todo.id ? item : null)));
  };

  const addNewTodo = (todo) => {
    setTodos((prevState) => [
      { value: todo, completed: false, id: todos.length + 1 },
      ...prevState,
    ]);
  };


  return (
    <div>
      <InputText addNewTodo={addNewTodo} filterTodos={filterTodos} />
      <TodoList
        todos={todos}
        deleteTodo={deleteTodo}
        changeStatus={changeStatus}
        todosType={todosType}
      />
    </div>
  );
```

**TodoList.js**

```
let todos = [];

  const getCompletedTodo = () => {
    todos = props.todos.filter((todo) => (todo.completed ? todo : null));
  };

  const getUnCompletedTodo = () => {
    todos = props.todos.filter((todo) => (!todo.completed ? todo : null));
  };

  const filterTodo = () => {
    switch (props.todosType) {
      case 'completed':
        getCompletedTodo();
        break;
      case 'uncompleted':
        getUnCompletedTodo();
        break;
      default:
        todos = props.todos;
    }
  };


  const deleteAnimation = (todo) => {
    const selectedTodo = document.getElementById(todo.id);
    selectedTodo.classList.add('fall');
    selectedTodo.addEventListener('transitionend', (event) => {
      props.deleteTodo(todo);
    });
  };


 <div>
      <div className="todo-container">
        <ul className="todo-list">
          {todos.map((todo, index) => {
            return (
              <div className="todo" id={todo.id} key={index}>
                <li
                  className={`todo-item ${todo.completed ? 'completed' : ''}`}
                >
                  {todo.value}
                </li>
                <button
                  className="complete-btn"
                  onClick={() => changeStatusHandler(todo)}
                >
                  <i className="fas fa-check"></i>
                </button>
                <button
                  onClick={() => deleteAnimation(todo)}
                  className="trash-btn"
                >
                  <i className="fas fa-trash"></i>
                </button>
              </div>
            );
          })}
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
```

But when I see my state in the browser console it is what I expected but on the web screen, it is not showing the exact todo that is available in the state.